# I want to Highlighted the cell based on time

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I want the cells to be highlighted based on timestamp value. That if timestamp value is between "10:00 a.m." to "11:00 a.m." then, the cells have highlighted with Green colour. If timestamp value is between "11:00 a.m." to "12:00 p.m." then, the cells have highlighted with Yellow colour. If timestamp value is greater than "12:00 p.m." then, the cells have highlighted with Red colour. So I want that conditional formatting in google sheets.

I try Some Conditions in Format cell, Conditional formatting but my problem is not resolved. So I want the solution for that.

Comment: Use the NOW and TIME functions.

Comment: Can you clarify if 12 pm should be yellow or red? You only need to use AND and TIME for this since conditional formatting needs TRUE or FALSE values.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the timestamp range to be formatted.

You need to create three Conditional formatting rules, each is a custom formula:

- `=and((hour(A2)+minute(A2)/60)>=10,(hour(A2)+minute(A2)/60)<=11)`: Green
- `=and((hour(A2)+minute(A2)/60)>=11,(hour(A2)+minute(A2)/60)<=12)`: Yellow
- `=(hour(A2)+minute(A2)/60)>=12`: Red

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `AND()` and `TIME()`

To apply conditional formatting using custom formulas, your formula should have an output of either 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE).

##### For timestamp:

- 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM: use `=AND(A1 \>= TIME(10, 0, 0), A1 < TIME(11, 0, 0))`
- 11:00 AM to 12:00 PM: use `=AND(A1 \>= TIME(11, 0, 0), A1 < TIME(12, 0, 0))`
- beyond 12:00 PM: use `=A1 \>= TIME(12, 0, 0)`

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [AND()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301?hl=en)
- [TIME()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093056?hl=en)